# Suppose $\gcd(2^5\times3^4 \times5^4 \times7 \times11, x) = d$ where $x$ and $d$ are integers. How many possible values of $d$ are there?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Originally I thought that $d$ could be any of the prime factors listed, or $1$ when $x$ is a prime number not listed on the left. But obviously if $x$ is an integer that decomposes to several of the factors on the left, there are far more possibilities. I do not believe they are infinite, there must be some upper limit. How do I find $d$ mathematically?

Comment: The same amount as how many positive divisors of $2^5\cdot3^4\cdot5^4\cdot7\cdot11$ there are

Comment: The gcd must be a factor of $2^5*3^4 *5^4 *7 *11$ and and factor of $2^5*3^4 *5^4 *7 *11$ can be a gcd if $x$ is that factor (or a multiple of that factor and a number relatively prime).  So all you need to do is count how many factors $2^5*3^4 *5^4 *7 *11$ has.

Comment: It can't be infinite because if $d\not \mid 2^5*3^4 *5^4 *7 *11$ then $d \ne \gcd$.  So the number of $d|2^5*3^4 *5^4 *7 *11$ is an upper limit.  If $d|2^5*3^4 *5^4 *7 *11$ and $x = d$ then $\gcd(2^5*3^4 *5^4 *7 *11,x) = d$.  So the number of $2^5*3^4 *5^4 *7 *11$ is not just an upper limit.  It is a lower limit.

Comment: You can write $4\cdot 5$ or $4\times5.$ Using an asterisk for that purpose is a workaround for situations when you're limited to symbols that are on the keyboard. $\qquad$

Comment: I see from your edit how to do $\times$. How can I write the dot?

Comment: $4\cdot 5=20$.  Inside the dollar signs write a backslash, then the letters cdot, then a space.

Comment: @SolidSnackDrive : Right-click on the expression, then choose "Show Math As" then choose "TeX Commands".

Comment: @OscarLanzi : You don't need that blank space after \cdot when what follows it is something other than a letter. But the blank space is still harmless then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X = \{$ possible values of $d\}$.

If $d = \gcd(2^5*3^4 *5^4 *7 *11, x)\in X$ and $\gcd(2^5*3^4 *5^4 *7 *11,x)|2^5*3^4 *5^4 *7 *11$ so $d|2^5*3^4 *5^4 *7 *11$

$X \subset \{$ factors of $2^5*3^4 *5^4 *7 *11\}$.

Now if $k$ is a factor of $2^5*3^4 *5^4 *7 *11$ then $\gcd(2^5*3^4 *5^4 *7 *11, k) = k$.

So $\{$ factors of $2^5*3^4 *5^4 *7 *11\} \subset X$.

$X = \{$ factors of $2^5*3^4 *5^4 *7 *11\}$

And do you know how many factors $2^5*3^4 *5^4 *7 *11$ has?  (If not... think about and research it).

....

$= \{2^a*3^b*5^c*7^d*11^e|0\le a \le 5; 0\le b\le 4;0\le c\le 4;0\le d\le 1; 0\le e \le 1\}$

So $|X| = $

$|\{2^a*3^b*5^c*7^d*11^e:0\le a \le 5; 0\le b\le 4;0\le c\le 4;0\le d\le 1; 0\le e \le 1\}| =$

$ |\{(a,b,c,d,e):0\le a \le 5; 0\le b\le 4;0\le c\le 4;0\le d\le 1; 0\le e \le 1\}|=$

$.... ????....$

Comment: That does make sense to me. There are 100 different factors for that number, correct?

Comment: Don't see how you got $100$.  A factor is of the form $2^a 3^b5^c7^d11^e$ and there $a$ can be anything from $0$ to $5$ (that 6 options).  And $b$ can be anything from $0$ to $4$ (that's 5 options) and so on.  I get that there are $6*5*5*2*2 = 600$ factors.

Comment: That is what I was trying to do, must have been a calculator error. Thanks, this makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $x=2^a3^b5^c7^d11^e$, where $0\leq a\leq 5$ and $0\leq b\leq 4$... then $d=x$ so we have $$(5+1)(4+1)(4+1)(1+1)(1+1)$$
possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Consider any possible value of $d$.  How many factors of $2$ does $d$ have?  How many factors of $3$ does $d$ have?  Etc.